# Making a pretty Base Map for QGIS and OpenLayers?

Tags: pyqgis, mapnik

I am developing a standalone QGIS application as well a web GIS using Openalyers. Both applications use GeoServer published WMS and WFS services of parcels as a base layer. I was wondering if it is possible to render this vector layers using Mapnik. What I wanted to have is a map styled the way OSM is which I think is rendered using Mapnik.

I know Mapnik has a Python API, which I could use with with PyQGIS, but would it be possible to use Mapnik to render on the QGIS map canvas? If yes, how?